# PhpSerial won't work on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: raspbian-buster

I have a php script using PhpSerial to dial out using a USB modem on a Pi3+ that works fine. That same script, however, will not dial out on a Pi4.

The USB modem appears as /dev/ttyACM0 on both the Pi3 and the Pi4 and the enable_uart=1 is active in both /boot/config.txt files.

The Pi4 is running the latest Buster image and has the most recent update and upgrade.

Is there something uniquely different between the Pi3 and the Pi4 that I am missing?

TIA,
Paul

Comment: Have you added www-data to the dialout group?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I did when initially trying to solve the issue. Stll no joy.